# I want to a batch script to clear the oracle database trace files which are older than 7 days. with "adrci> purge -age 10080 -type TRACE"

Tags: oracle, powershell, shell, plsql

I want to a batch script to clear the oracle database trace files which are older than 7 days.

I do manually delete like:

```
adrci> purge -age 10080 -type TRACE
```

The bash script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#cleanup Automatic Diagnostic Repository (i.e trace files)

#set oracle_home (have a script with your home info)
source ~/OracleHomeScript.sh

#list current repo size
echo ""
echo "##############size before############"
du -shx /u01/app/oracle/diag

echo ""
echo "Listing diag directory homes..."
echo ""
ADR_HOMES=`adrci exec="show homes" |grep -v "ADR Homes:"`
adrci exec="show homes" |grep -v "ADR Homes:"
echo ""
echo ""

#Set-up loop for each home
#

for f in $ADR_HOMES
do
echo "purging $f older than 1 week"
#Slow ADRCI Execution When Purging Files After Upgrade to 12.2 (Doc ID 2335738.1)
adrci exec="set homepath $f; purge -age 10080 -nolog"
done

#list ADR repo size after
echo ""
echo "##############size after############"
du -shx /u01/app/oracle/diag
```

Comment: Batch or Bash? And what's the question? Does your script have a problem?

Comment: And apply the appropriate tags. This has nothing to do with powershell

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: I want a batch script. I provided bash script for same. Need to convert to batch script from bash shell script.

Answer (score 0):

```
param(
[Int]$Purge_days=7
)

$NLS_LANG="AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251"
$ORACLE_HOME_BIN="D:\app\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\"
$Purge_time=$Purge_days*60*24

function set_oracle_env
{
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NLS_LANG", $NLS_LANG , [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::PROCESS)
$PATH_USER=[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::PROCESS)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $ORACLE_HOME_BIN+";"+ $PATH_USER, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::PROCESS)

}

function du($path=".") {
    $path_short=$path -replace "\\[^\\]*(?:\\)?$"
    Get-ChildItem $path_short |
    ForEach-Object {
        if  ($_.FullName -eq $path ) {
        $file = $_
        Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse $_.FullName | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum |
        Select-Object -Property  @{Name="Name";Expression={$file.FullName}},
                                 @{Name="Size(MB)";Expression={[math]::round(($_.Sum / 1MB),2)}} # round 2 decimal places


        }
    }
}

# set ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_SID NLS_LANG
set_oracle_env

echo ""
echo "Show ADR base "

$ADR_BASE=adrci exec="show base" |%{$_.split('"')[1]}

$ADR_BASE=$ADR_BASE+"\"
echo $ADR_BASE
echo ""

echo "Listing diag directory homes..."
echo ""
$ADR_HOMES=adrci exec="show homes" |select-string  -pattern  'ADR Homes:' -NotMatch
echo $ADR_HOMES
echo ""

echo "##############size before############"
foreach ( $ADR_HOME in $ADR_HOMES )
{
    $diag_dir=$ADR_BASE + $ADR_HOME
   
    $size=du $diag_dir

    echo $size

}

#Set-up loop for each home

foreach ( $ADR_HOME in $ADR_HOMES )
{
echo "purging $ADR_HOME older than $Purge_days days"
$ADR_HOME_COMMAND=$ADR_HOME -replace '\\','\\';
$adrci_command="set home $ADR_HOME_COMMAND; purge -age $Purge_time "
echo $adrci_command
adrci exec=$adrci_command
}


echo ""
echo "##############size after############"

foreach ( $ADR_HOME in $ADR_HOMES )
{
    $diag_dir=$ADR_BASE + $ADR_HOME
   
    $size=du $diag_dir

    echo $size

}
```

For example output

```
\upwork\stackoverflow\adrci>powershell .\purge_trace.ps1                                                                                                                             
Show ADR base

D:\app\                                                                                                                                                                            


Listing diag directory homes...


diag\clients\user_oracle\host_4248464613_107
diag\rdbms\test\test
diag\tnslsnr\DEMIN\listener


##############size before############

Name     : D:\app\diag\clients\user_oracle\host_4248464613_107
Size(MB) : 0,27


Name     : D:\app\diag\rdbms\test\test
Size(MB) : 15,92


Name     : D:\app\diag\tnslsnr\DEMIN\listener
Size(MB) : 0,72

purging diag\clients\user_oracle\host_4248464613_107 older than 7 days
set home diag\\clients\\user_oracle\\host_4248464613_107; purge -age 10080
purging diag\rdbms\test\test older than 7 days
set home diag\\rdbms\\test\\test; purge -age 10080
purging diag\tnslsnr\DEMIN\listener older than 7 days
set home diag\\tnslsnr\\DEMIN\\listener; purge -age 10080

##############size after############

Name     : D:\app\diag\clients\user_oracle\host_4248464613_107
Size(MB) : 0,58


Name     : D:\app\diag\rdbms\test\test
Size(MB) : 10,93


Name     : D:\app\diag\tnslsnr\DEMIN\listener
Size(MB) : 1,04
```

Answer (score 0):

set SHORTP_POLICY to number of hours required as below

```
adrci> set control (SHORTP_POLICY = 360)
adrci> set control (LONGP_POLICY= 2190)
```